# How to print nested values along with parent level values using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": id1,
            "arr": [
                {
                    "arrId": arrId11,
                    "someOtherKey1": xxx,
                    "someOtherKey2": xxx,
                },
                {
                    "arrId": arrId12,
                    "someOtherKey1": xxx,
                    "someOtherKey2": xxx,
                }
            ],
            "otherParentLevelKey": yyyyy
        },
        {
            "id": id2,
            "arr": [
                {
                    "arrId": arrId21,
                    "someOtherKey1": xxx,
                    "someOtherKey2": xxx,
                },
                {
                    "arrId": arrId22,
                    "someOtherKey1": xxx,
                    "someOtherKey2": xxx,
                }
            ],
            "otherParentLevelKey": yyyyy
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want the following output

```
{
    "id": id1,
    "arr": [
        {
            "arrId": arrId11
        },
        {
            "arrId": arrId11
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": id2,
    "arr": [
        {
            "arrId": arrId21
        },
        {
            "arrId": arrId21
        }
    ],
}
```

I tried the following query but it’s not syntactically correct

```
jsonArray | jq '.data[] | {id, arr[].arrId}'
```

The approach I am using right now is something like the below. The output is something I can manage but I was wondering if there is a way with jq to achieve the one I wanted above.

```
jsonArray | jq '.data[] | [{(.id): .arr[].arrId}]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `map` to retain the array while modifying (here: reducing) it to your needs:

```sh
jq '.data[] | {id, arr: .arr | map({arrId})}'
```

```json
{
  "id": "id1",
  "arr": [
    {
      "arrId": "arrId11"
    },
    {
      "arrId": "arrId12"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "id2",
  "arr": [
    {
      "arrId": "arrId21"
    },
    {
      "arrId": "arrId22"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/l2bkUBXJKVy)